# Permanently disable specific stylus input on unix

Tags: 20.04, xorg, touchscreen

I have an old laptop with a cracked screen running Ubuntu 20.04. The touchscreen goes absolutely nuts everytime the computer restarts.

It seems under xinput -list there is a toushscreen device, a stylus pen, and a stylus eraser. I have been able to disable the touchscreen input using blacklisting touschreen input in xorg/conf.d method: blacklisting touschreen input in xorg/conf.d
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo6yd.png)
However, that still leaves the stylus input which i have to manually disable with the xinput disable command everytime I boot the computer.

If anyone knows how I could blacklist that as well I would be forever indebted. Here is my xinput -list (Note the ELAN strings) xinput -list description

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXhbR.png)